# Polymer - What approach would be the best for a website with lots of views filled with dynamic datas

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have to make a website where after user sing's in, he gets a lot of dynamic data, like a list of paper tabs that should be visible for him in one place, then some in another ( there will be a lot of views where user can switch betweeen their content all the time) . Im new to polymer and only solution that came to my mind is to keep passing all the data like this:
my-app -> child view 1 -> child view 2 -> child view 3 -> etc. etc. ( there can be a lot of them) untill it finally gets to where i need it to and gets displayed.

Is this the best way to do this? Hell, im not even sure it will work for me since its hard for me to know what will i have to display :|

Comment: think this will hepl Thinking in Polymer  https://youtu.be/ZDjiUmx51y8

Answer (score 0):

You have several options that do not require you to pass down each and every object/property through your component tree:

If you only need to pass data one way (without being able to change it at its destination components), you can use [iron-meta](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-meta), a monostate implementation-as-a-component.
Using this, you define/fetch/create data in one element (e.g. your app's root component) and store it in a globally accessible way. Other components just instantiate `iron-meta` and fetch their data via a key, without being able to propagate back changes.

If you want a fully-fledged state management solution, take a look at https://www.webcomponents.org/element/tur-nr/polymer-redux instead.

There's also [this excellent article on state management in Polymer](https://www.captaincodeman.com/2017/07/06/managing-state-in-polymer-20-beyond-parent-child-binding) by @CaptainCodeman.